# 異なる幅のtrを持つtableで特定のtrに境界線を引く方法

Tags: css

下記の構造のテーブルで、「値３－１」の下部にテーブルの最大幅で境界線を引きたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

条件として、
・CSSは変更できずstyleの変更しかできない
・境界線以外の見た目は変えない
というものがあります。

仮でtbodyのstyleに境界線の設定をしていますが、これは表示されません。
tableのborder-collapseをcollapseに変更すると境界線は表示されますが
見た目が変わってしまいます。

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}

tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}

td, th {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}

th {
  background-color: green;
    border-color: #3498db;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>項目名１</th>
    <th>項目名２</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>値１－１</td>
    <td>値２－１</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>項目名３</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="border-bottom: medium dotted rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  <tr>
    <td>値３－１</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>項目名１</th>
    <th>項目名２</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>値１－２</td>
    <td>値２－２</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>項目名３</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>値３－２</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 3-1を所有しているtdタグをcolspanでセルの結合をしてもいいですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。セルの結合は見た目が変わるので不可となります。

Answer (score 1):

```
<tbody style="box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 red inset;">
```

境界線ではないが、見た目は線に見える案です。
dottedは無理ですが。